# Using mocha parallel option with dynamically generated Mocha test suite

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, mocha.js

I have some sample Mocha codes as below:

```js
function runMochaTestSuite(testSuite) {
  describe(testSuite.name, function () {
    for (testCase of testSuite.testCases) {
      it(testCase.name, function () {
      });
    }
  });
}
const myTestSuites = [
  {
    name: "Test Suite 1",
    testCases: [
      {
        name: "Test Case 1-1",
      },
      {
        name: "Test Case 1-2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Test Suite 2",
    testCases: [
      {
        name: "Test Case 2-1",
      },
      {
        name: "Test Case 2-2",
      },
    ],
  },
];
for (suite of myTestSuites) {
  runMochaTestSuite(suite);
}
```

I run this ok with Mocha version 7.

how can I make use of new parallel option in version 8 to run the test suites like above in parallel?

Much appreciated for your help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also please advise if any of you knows a third party module that can archive this?
Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The [documentation](https://mochajs.org/#-parallel-p) says:

> Use the --parallel flag to run tests in a worker pool.
> Each test file will be put into a queue and executed as workers become available.

The parallel execution is file based, not single test based.